# How can I filter an observable array?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, firebase

I'm trying to filter an array of strings from db firebase by clicking on button and calling method to filter. My problem is that nothing is happening.

What am I doing wrong ?

service

```
images: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
   this.images = this.db.list("/images").valueChanges();

  }
```

component

```
images: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private firebase: FirebaseService) {
    this.images = firebase.images;

  }

  loadImages(category: string) {
    return this.images.subscribe(x => x.filter(x => x === category))
  }
```

html

```
<button (click)="loadImages(image1)" >Filter</button>
  <div *ngFor="let image of images | async">
    <h2>{{image}}</h2>

  </div>
```

firebase db:

[image1, image2, image3, image4] - only for test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Observable with the map operator to display the data. Refer to this stackblitz, I replaced the database retrieval with an Observable containing an array of strings for demonstration purposes:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/load-and-filter-from-service

service:

```
retrieveImages(): Observable<any> {
  // replace with firebase call this.db.list("/images").valueChanges();
  return of(['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4']);
}
```

component:

```
public images$: Observable<any>;

constructor(private firebase: FirebaseService) {
  ;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadImages('image1');
}

loadImages(category: string) {
  this.images$ = this.firebase.retrieveImages().pipe(
    map(x => x.filter(x => x === category))
  );
}
```

html:

```
<button (click)="loadImages('image1')" >Filter 1</button>
<button (click)="loadImages('image2')" >Filter 2</button>
<button (click)="loadImages('image3')" >Filter 3</button>
<button (click)="loadImages('image4')" >Filter 4</button>
<div *ngFor="let image of (images$ | async)">
    <h2>{{image}}</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if indeed you are trying to filter by whatever is in the string of category, a simple string comparison will always result in false. Take this for example.

```
const x = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4'];
console.log(x.filter(x => x === 'image'));
// Resulting log will be an Array wtih length 0 because image1 !== image
```

However if you are looking for a substring of the string then you can see if the category is a substring of the string.

```
const x = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4'];
console.log(x.filter(x => x.includes('image')));
```

Whether it is observable or not, the end result of your subscribe is the actual data, which you can run the filter on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructor method in service, you can create a new method which will return the image data.

Service:

```
getImages() {
    return this.db.list("/images").valueChanges();
}
```

In component, you can call the service method `getImages()`.

Comment: try to set this to images: Observable<any[]>